# Vaadin 7 Portlets error on Glassfish V3

Tags: glassfish, liferay, vaadin, portlet

I am creating a Vaadin (version 7) portlet, my development environment is eclipse 4.3.1 + tomcat-7.0.27+Liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2, I am checking the stuff on tomcat and the portlet runs fine there. 
Now my deployment environment is Glassfish-3.1.2+Liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2, the same portlet and the log message is: "sampleApp was successfully deployed", the Portlet error is "Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./../../VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js".

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1):

From Book of Vaadin:

Liferay 6.1, [...], comes bundled with an older Vaadin 6 version. If you want to use Vaadin 7, you need to remove the bundled version and install the newer one manually as described in this chapter.

In these instructions, we assume that you use Liferay bundled with Apache Tomcat, although you can use almost any other application server with Liferay just as well.

12.5.1. **Removing the Bundled Installation**

Before installing a new Vaadin version, you need to remove the version bundled with Liferay. You need to remove the Vaadin library JAR from the library directory of the portal and the VAADIN directory from under the root context. For example, with Tomcat, they are usually located as follows:

tomcat-x.x.x/webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN

tomcat-x.x.x/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/vaadin.jar

12.5.2. **Installing Vaadin**

Get the Vaadin installation package from the Vaadin download page
Extract the following Vaadin JARs from the installation package:

vaadin-server.jar,
vaadin-shared.jar,

as well as the  vaadin-shared-deps.jar and  jsoup.jar dependencies from the  lib folder

Rename the JAR files as they were listed above, without the version number
Put the libraries in tomcat-x.x.x/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/

Extract the VAADIN folders from  vaadin-server.jar,  vaadin-themes.jar, and vaadin-client-compiled.jar and copy their contents to tomcat-x.x.x/webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN.

$ cd tomcat-x.x.x/webapps/ROOT/html

$ unzip path-to/vaadin-server-7.1.0.jar 'VAADIN/*'

$ unzip path-to/vaadin-themes-7.1.0.jar 'VAADIN/*'

$ unzip path-to/vaadin-client-compiled-7.1.0.jar 'VAADIN/*'

You need to define the widget set, the theme, and the JAR in the  portal-ext.properties configuration file for Liferay, as described earlier. The file should normally be placed in the Liferay installation directory. See Liferay documentation for details on the configuration file.

Below is an example of a portal-ext.properties file:

> # Path under which the VAADIN directory is located.
>   # (/html is the default so it is not needed.)
>   # vaadin.resources.path=/html
>
> # Portal-wide widget set
>   vaadin.widgetset=com.vaadin.portal.gwt.PortalDefaultWidgetSet
>
> # Theme to use
>   vaadin.theme=liferay

Comment: In fact that solve the problem. In case you need to run both versions in the same Liferay instance you should be able by creating separate VAADIN folders for both versions. More information and some scritps to automate the change here [Vaadin Wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating+Vaadin+7+with+Liferay)

Comment: This issue - the Portlet error is "Failed to load the bootstrap javascript: ./../../VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js" is too much vague. Look on stack trace in development environment. It can have many reasons, but many times it is binded with missing or badly setted path to VaadinServlet. Check, if your settings in annotaion in portlet is proper, or check web.xml descriptor. I.e. it should be like this for Vaddin version 7.5.0 (Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse 2.3.2):  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>VaadinServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>